# Why do I get an error when I try to retrieve the image coordinates via $_POST?

Tags: php, imagemap

While trying to handle image maps, I get an error if I try to retrieve the coordinates via `$_POST` . I do not understand the reason though.

For the following `form` :

```
<form method='post' action='action_script.php'>
    <input name='coordinates' type='image' src='./rabbits.jpg' />
</form>
```

this is the `action_script.php` script :

```
<?php
echo "Coordinates : {$_POST['coordinates_x']} and {$_POST['coordinates_y']} ";
```

This script throws an error,saying `coordinates_x` and `coordinates_y` are undefined. But if I replace `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST` it works fine and tells the coordinates. Why do I get an error when I use `$_POST` ?

*The following script doesn't produce an error :*

```
<?php
echo "Coordinates: {$_REQUEST['coordinates_x']} and {$_REQUEST['coordinates_y']}";
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you have `method="post"`? If you add a text input to the form, and submit it, does that show up in `$_POST`?

Comment: use `$_POST['coordinates']`, its saying undefined because your name for the input is coordinates not coordinates_x

Comment: @ColinMorelli yes. It does show up the text

Comment: $_REQUEST is a combo of both GET, POST, COOKIES, etc... If $_POST doesn't work, then most likely you're not actually doing a post (maybe there's a server-side redirect in play). Try `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your full code? You don't seem to be showing us the submit button etc.

But what matters is that you are ASSUMING that everything went well and was posted, never assume anything, use the arbitrary operator to actually check if anything was posted:

```
$xCord = isset($_POST['coordinates_x']) ? $_POST['coordinates_x'] : false;
$yCord = isset($_POST['coordinates_x']) ? $_POST['coordinates_x'] : false;
```

And, like pointed out, you should really be doing something like

```
$xCord = isset($_POST['coordinates']) ? $_POST['coordinates'] : false;
```

And if It's really something that you can strip down then this shouldn't ruin the data.

Now you can actually check if it was successfully posted, it it turns out that It's false then you're simply doing something wrong.

Now It makes sense to echo

```
echo "Coordinates: $xCord and $yCord";
```

But then again, I find your form a little funky. Try this new approach and give us the full code.